# spring cloud stream SOURCE with key,value type of message

Tags: spring, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, kafka-producer-api

I was trying to send a message with key, value pair using spring cloud stream. I am not able to find any API for that. org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel only has payload as part of send function.Using Kafka Template this can be achieved although. Is that the only way to produce key,value kind of message.As KafkaTemplate is part of spring for apache kafka, i was hoping there is a abstraction available for the same in spring cloud stream. Please suggest.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

For the purpose of your question you can look at spring-cloud-stream as higher level abstraction over more low level APIs such as spring-kafka (if kafka binder is used), spring-integration etc. In other words you don't need to either send or receive anything explicitly within the scope of the framework. It will do the sending and receiving for you; That's the core feature of the framework - to bind execution of your code to input and output destinations managed by your broker.
All you need to do for your case is produce a `Message`. For example, here is a fully functioning application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public static class SupplierConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Supplier<String> stringSupplier() {
        return () -> "Hello from Supplier";
    }
}
```

While all you did is produced a String the framework will wrap it into Message and will send it to Kafka (providing you're using Kafka binder).
If you need to control explicitly the value of the key, you can return an actual instance of the Message with `kafka_messageKey` set. For example;

```
@SpringBootApplication
public static class SupplierConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Supplier<Message<?>> stringSupplier() {
        return () -> MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello from Supplier")
                   .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "blah")
                   .build();
    }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_suppliers_sources)

Also, notice we're moving away from annotation-based programming model and into a much simpler functional model.

Comment: Thanks for you input. Just to confirm KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY is same as KEY in KAFKATemplate? I need to join two KTables based on this key. Please confirm. Also i was using the same code to produce a message. As soon as i add the  KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY , messages are no longer producing as JSON. Its getting produced as bytes.I am using setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON).

Comment: What  I don't understand is how I can invoke the supplier to send a message?

Comment: You don't. It get's invoked by itself - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_suppliers_sources

Comment: its Stream FP API compatible with the flow when I need to produce a message somewhere from an application? For example I register user and send UserRegistered message? I can't find it in documentation. with legacy API it is possible via MessageChannel

Comment: Sadly, I am suspecting you probably didn't look as it is in the documentation i've linked to in the previous comment. But here is the specific section - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_foreign_event_driven_sources

Comment: Sorry, I was looking to the wrong documentation wher this piece is missing: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-producing-consuming-messages, Thank you

Comment: In Spring Kafka 3.x.x there is no longer `KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY`. It has been replaced with `KafkaHeaders.KEY`